# Disabling "Review_List" in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I can not find where I disable this in Magento 1.8 CE. I have only been able to turn it off by deleting the line of code below:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>`

in my

`app/design/frontend/default/galaelectronues/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

but I would think there was an option to turn it off somewhere. I am using a theme "Gala Electronues" if that is of any help. I just don't like the idea of going in and manually editing a file just to turn something off like that.

Comment: are you want to disable Review module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Go to System --> Configuration.
3. Click on Advanced in left menu.
4. Select "Disable" for "Mage_Review" module under Disable Modules Output list.

It will disable review module and remove it from frontend.